# JS Прокрутка внутри блока при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется вот такой вот блок, элементу ul заданна высота 200px и overflow: hidden;
[image: список]

В списке 10 li, если их больше они скрываются.
Как сделать прокрутки внутри блока при наведении и при клике на кнопку "другие"
Пытался реализовать, но получалась что он проматывал не сам блок ul, а целевую страницу сайта.

Для прокрутки при наведение на ul использую "jQuery Mousewheel"
Вызов

```
$('.h-filter__ul').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    this.scrollTop = (scrollTop + ((event.deltaY * event.deltaFactor)* -1));
});
```

А вот скрипт плавной прокрутки
`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // если в href начинается с # или ., то ловим клик
    $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click( function(){

        // возьмем содержимое атрибута href
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');

        // проверим существование элемента чтобы избежать ошибки
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
            // анимируем скроолинг к элементу scroll_el
            $('html, body').animate({ 
                scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top 
            }, 1100);
        }
        return false; // выключаем стандартное действие

    });
});
```

`

Comment: а как именно вы сейчас делаете прокрутку?

Comment: В нутри списка ul, делаю в конце еще один элемент li с классом bottom1 - для первого блока. И при клике посылаю перемотку до этого блока, но прокручивает всю страницу

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, так легче будет разобраться

Comment: добавил код....

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой части:

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top 
}, 1100);
```

Вы тут явно пишите что хотите крутить всю страницу. Если хотите крутить блок то нужно поменять селектор:

```
$('.h-filter__ul').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top 
}, 1100);
```

Comment: А что делать если элементов .h-filter__ul целых 4, при щелчке на кнопку "Другие" я прокручиваю все, а нужно прокрутить только соответствующий список

Comment: тогда надо получить этот элемент исходя из щелкнутого тега а. это достигается this. This - хранит именно элемет с которым мы взаимодействуем. $(this).parent() - вернет родителя этого элемента. Если возникнут трудности с тем чтобы достать нужный элемент то добавьте HTML в вопрос и я помогу